# Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.3.1 vs 2.1.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I try to create a web server based on SpringBootStarterParent. Can somebody explain me, why the first solution works, but the second does not? I don't get the clue...

SOLUTION 1:

In my pom.xml I have these two sections:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <...>
    </dependencies>
```

SOLUTION 2:

Here i just have one section:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

So my question: At solution 2, the mapping of the Controllers does not work (Result are 404 errors).
If I just change the version of the starter-pom to 2.1.2 and add the thymelead-dependency (at solution 1) it works. I can not compile, if I add this dependency in solution 2 - here I will get "Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar:2.3.1.RELEASE" error.

Is there any explanation or any other "dependency-expression" for thymeleaf for 2.3.1, that I have to add at solution 2?

UPDATE: Its quite weird: In my m2-dir the thymeleaf-jar-file was missing, i put it in manually. Now i can compile it, but the mapping of GetMapping dont work. If i just change back to 2.1.2, i works like a charm ... Are there any differences of using (@Controller, @GetMapping and a corresponding welcome.html file) from 2.1.2 to 2.3.1 ?

Comment: The spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency does exist in Maven, so probably something is wrong in your Maven config or local repository: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf/2.3.1.RELEASE/jar

Comment: I have added an update above.

Comment: "In my m2-dir the thymeleaf-jar-file was missing, i put it in manually" -> You should never have to put jars manually in `~/.m2/repository`. What version of Maven are you using? Remove what you manually put there and run `mvn verify`. It should download the dependencies.

Comment: I use Mvn 3.6.3. I actually did "mvn clean package". It should download missing dependecies as well. The problem was, it did not work correctly. Now, I have deleted the hole directory "org.springframework" including all subdirectories. Now, it downloaded all spring dependencies again and it seemed to be working ...